# Making an object that travels with constant speed

Tags: c#, timer

I am using a timer to animate an object to travel at constant speed.

Here is my code:

```
  Class class1 = new Class();
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {    
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        class1.Draw(g);
    }
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x += 1;
        class1.Move(x/2, x/2);
        Invalidate();

    }
```

Class:

```
  class Class
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        SolidBrush Brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        g.FillRectangle(Brush, x, y, 10, 10);
    }

    public void Move(int X, int Y)
    {
        x = x + X/3;
        y = y + Y/3;
    }
}
```

The square is accelerating, any ideas on how to make it travel with constant speed?

Comment: Pick some better names and the issue will become a lot clearer. `x` is a position, `dx` is a speed. `Move(x/2, x/2);` does look like accelerating away from the origin.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incrementing the "x" each time, which is then used as a delta for the move.  Comment out:

```
 // x += 1;
 class1.Move(x/2, x/2);
```

You'll also need to specify a default "x" for this.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but won't the square just be stationary with this code?

Comment: @user2432378 Not if you set x to a non-zero value at the start.  The "Move" method increments:  `x = x + X/3;`

Comment: Thank you! Much appriciated